# how to set css in javascript for multiple elements with for loop

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have to design the reserved seats according to the sent photo.
According to the loop I wrote in javascript, how can I organize the position of the li tag with javascript so that I don't need to write a separate css in the css file for each seat separately like this:

```
.seates ul.rowE li:nth-child(1) {
    transform: rotate(-25deg);
    left: 0px;
    top: 0;
}

.seates ul.rowE li:nth-child(2) {
    transform: rotate(-26deg);
    left: 45px;
    top: -23px;
}

.seates ul.rowE li:nth-child(3) {
    transform: rotate(-26deg);
    left: 90px;
    top: -30px;
}
```

```js
let rowE = document.querySelector("#rowE");
      for (var i = 1; i <= 23; i++) {
        rowE.innerHTML += `
          <li>
            <button>
              <p>${i}</p>
            </button>
          </li>
        `;
      }

var myButton = document.querySelectorAll("#rowE li button");
  myButton.forEach(function (b, i) {
    b.addEventListener("click", function () {
      console.log("button :>> ", i + 1);
  });
});
```

```css
.seates {
    width: 70%;
    margin: auto;
}

.seates ul.row {
    display: flex;
    direction: ltr;
    align-items: center;
    border: 2px solid gold;
    justify-content: center;
    position: relative;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100%;
    border-radius: 50% 50% 0 0;
    list-style: none;
}
.seates ul.rowE li{
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="seates">
  <ul class="row" id="rowE"></ul>
</div>
```

[image]
So that I can create an imaginary half circle according to the photo

Is there a javascript way to solve this problem?

Can you guide me or show me an example of this?

I would be grateful if you could guide me.

Comment: You can use css variables for this i think. Add style attribute with `--row-rotate: xdeg; --row-left: xpx; --rowright: xpx` using js in a loop for each elements. Which you can use in css. This way each element uses the css variable from dom element

Comment: Can you explain more or show me an example?

Comment: here is the example https://jsfiddle.net/za1fwb5L/